# Using class with smarty

Tags: php, function, class, smarty, undefined

I'm very new to php and smarty.

I'm trying to call a function but can't understand why it's undefined.
Here is my code:

```
include 'header.php';

include 'template/footer.tpl';

class indexmessage{

    function message(){

        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM hovedside WHERE id = 1");
        $query->execute;

        return fetchAll();

    }
}


$smarty->assign('indexmessage', message());

$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `message` function is a method of `indexmessage`. This has nothing to do with Smarty, it's just basic OOP.

```
$index = new indexmessage();
$message = $index->message();
$smarty->assign("indexmessage",$message);
```

Comment: So when i call it, I use {$message}? I got this error now 

Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$execute in my_path/index.php on line 14

Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetchAll() in my_path/index.php on line 16

Comment: That'll be because it should be `$query->execute();` and `return $query->fetchAll();` You really should read up on basic OOP before going any further...

Comment: Ty :) Yeah I'm trying ^^,